# How to enable message when control is active in html/angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I've a form for user to Add an entry. Fiels such as Id, Title, Genre, Rating.

I just need the control to display an example message when user click the control(ie. when control is in active). I've done the validation when user leaves the field empty.

Current code of one of my control

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="MovieTitle" class="form-control" name="MovTitle" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/" placeholder="Movie Title" required title="Enter Movie Title" />
                    </div>
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="adduserform.MovTitle.$dirty && adduserform.MovTitle.$invalid">
                        <br />
                        <span ng-show="adduserform.MovTitle.$error.required" class="spnmsg">Field must not be empty</span>
                        <span ng-show="adduserform.MovTitle.$error.pattern" class="spnmsg">No Special Characters Allowed</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

So here how can i let the user to pop-up a div below my control(Title) with a message of

"Example : Iron Man/SpiderMan/Avatar"

and div to be hidden when he leaves the control..Meanwhile it should not violate my validation codes also i coded above...

So far my validation msg triggers when

*User leaves field empty after entered and deleted

*User tries to enter special Characs

Hope i've cleared what is in my mind....Help me please

Comment: Use $pristine like <div ng-show="formName.$prisitne> to be popup. This div will be shown when the page is loaded. You can place it below the control(Title). Hope it is clear

Comment: thanks...but i dont want it when page loads friend....i need it to be popped when user intracts with control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` for what you want.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" ng-model="MovieTitle" class="form-control" 
               name="MovTitle" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/" 
               ng-focus="inputFocused=true" ng-blur="inputFocused=false"
               placeholder="Movie Title" required title="Enter Movie Title" />
     </div>
     <span style="color:red" ng-show="inputFocused">
      //your message goes here                   
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: one more help.....i've another div which will be visible on button click and if i do so, this above div with form will be hidden. Problem is when i come back to this div again, the controls(title, Id) are hoding the values which user entered..how to reset or clear the control values when i move to other div

Comment: you have to clear the value manually. On your button click event call a function using ng-click and set your binding i.e. MovieTitle="" in the function

Comment: great.....if u mind if i query one more...hope not
well like Title control, i've another control as 'Cast' in my form. In DB, this cast attribute is array data type.
So how can i pass the value entered in UI to db as array bec now it is passing as null...somethin to do in angular....any idea?